# Understanding polymorphism

Tags: java, class, oop

In my class hierarchy, there's a superclass called "**Media type**" ."**Sound**" and "**Image**" are two sub-classes of it.For both Sound and Image classes I want to have a method as **quality()**.But the way the method quality() works when it is used under sound class and image class is different.What I want to know is is in the superclass "Media type" can I add two methods with the same name quality(),which according to the object type(whether it is sound or image type object) decides which **quality()** method should be functioned. Is this what is known as polymorphism?

Comment: Why don't you try it out instead of asking? It will give you many more insights

Answer (score 4):

> What I want to know is is in the superclass "Media type" can I add two
>   methods with the same name quality(),which according to the object
>   type(whether it is sound or image type object) decides which quality()
>   method should be functioned.

Well, you've partially understood polymorphism. The beauty of polymorphism is that you don't *need* two methods - **you only need one**. Define method `quality()` in the parent class, and then implement the specific behavior in each child class. If you have a few `Media` objects you can call `quality()` on them all - at run time, the correct concrete class' implementation will be called.

```
ArrayList<Media> m = new ArrayList<>();
m.add(new Sound());
m.add(new Image());

for(Media obj: m) {
    obj.quality();  // polymorphism in action!
}
```

Try it out. Good luck!

Comment: @Lokesh did you downvote everybody who answered this question?

Comment: Only the answers which didn't address the point . "What I want to know is is in the superclass "Media type" can I add two methods with the same name quality(),which according to the object type(whether it is sound or image type object) decides which quality() method should be functioned." This is what is asked.

Comment: @Lokesh You're right - the OP asked if he can add two methods. And I've addressed this point now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You add a method named `quality()` to `MediaType` class and then you override it in `Sound` and `Image` classes. This way whenever `quality()` is called any `MediaType`, the right `quality()` method for each object (`Sound` or `Image`) is called. And yes, it's polymorphism this way.

Comment: Finally, an answer which is entirely correct.  +1.  It's sad that such a basic question should have been answered so poorly by so-called experts.

Comment: @David Wallace: Yes, and it's even more sad when some guys -1 the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of Polymorphism:

You have a general (parent) class where `method()` exists and you add subclasses (inherit) where the same `method()` exists, but might be overriden.

For all of the classes above you can call `method()` and the corresponding `method()` would be called.

Answer (score -3):

I am a beginning programmer but I might be able to help you a little bit.
As I understand, polymorphism is the ability of a class to behave as if it had two different types. The compile-time (current type) type and the run-time (true type) type. If you have a sound type instance and assign it to a media type instance, its run-time type will be sound, but its compile-time type will be media. This means that to call a method that method will need to exist in your compile-time type class (media), but the actual method called will be the method with the same features contained within your run-time class (sound).

Comment: That is **not** what polymorphism is.

Comment: The dictionary definition of polymorphism refers to a principle in biology in which an organism or species can have many different forms or stages. This principle can also be applied to object-oriented programming and languages like the Java language. Subclasses of a class can define their own unique behaviors and yet share some of the same functionality of the parent class.

Comment: I think you might be getting tripped up in thinking that these classes are behaving differently at run time vs compile time.

Comment: If you don't know the answer, then don't answer the question.